# How to write an equation as a function argument?

Tags: r

The function I created runs correctly on my computer. However, I'm trying to check for errors by `devtools :: check_built ()` and I'm having problems with the `myeq` argument. The letters `d` and `h` represent my columns `simple1 $ Diameter (cm)` and `simple1 $ Height (m)`, respectively.

```
indvol(x = simple1, mens="plot", myeq = 0.000065661*d^(2.475293)*h^(0.300022))


> head(simple1)
  Plot Individual               Specie Height (m) Diameter (cm)
1    1          1 Cariocar braziliense        7.5         22.60
2    1          1 Cariocar braziliense        7.5         25.78
3    1          1 Cariocar braziliense        7.5         46.15
4    1          1 Cariocar braziliense        7.5          9.55
5    1          2     Qualya parvifora        2.0          5.73
6    1          3    Magonia pubescens        4.0          5.73
```

The following error appears:

```
Error in indvol(x = simple1, mens = "plot", myeq = 6.5661e-05 * d^(2.475293) *  : 
    object 'd' not found
  Execution halted
```

The part dealing with the `myeq` argument within the function is:

```
 if(mens=="plot"){
    colnames(x)[5]<-"d"
    colnames(x)[4]<-"h"

   d<-x[,5]
   h<-x[,4]
}

  x$`Volume (m3)` <- eval(substitute(myeq), envir=x); x
```

Would anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to capture the expression without evaluating it. You can do this with `match.call()`:

```r
indvol <- function(x, mens, myeq)
{
  mc <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
  
  if (mens == "plot")
  {
    colnames(x)[5] <- "d"
    colnames(x)[4] <- "h"
    d <- x[, 5]
    h <- x[, 4]
  }
  
  x$`Volume (m3)` <- eval(mc$myeq, envir = x)
  
  return(x)
}
```

So the function now works as expected:

```r
indvol(x = simple1, mens="plot", myeq = 0.000065661*d^(2.475293)*h^(0.300022))
#>   Plot Individual               Specie   h     d Volume (m3)
#> 1    1          1 Cariocar braziliense 7.5 22.60 0.270184396
#> 2    1          1 Cariocar braziliense 7.5 25.78 0.374268984
#> 3    1          1  Carioca braziliense 7.5 46.15 1.581822308
#> 4    1          1  Carioca braziliense 7.5  9.55 0.032036171
#> 5    1          2     Qualya parvifora 2.0  5.73 0.006085243
#> 6    1          3     Magoni pubescens 4.0  5.73 0.007491927
```

As a design point though, it might be better to allow users to just use the column names of the passed data frame into the function.

---

**Data**

```
simple1 <- structure(list(Plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Individual = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Specie = c("Cariocar braziliense", "Cariocar braziliense", 
    "Carioca braziliense", "Carioca braziliense", "Qualya parvifora", 
    "Magoni pubescens"), `Height (m)` = c(7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 2, 4), 
    `Diameter (cm)` = c(22.6, 25.78, 46.15, 9.55, 5.73, 5.73)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Allan, Thanks. But the error remained the same, does not find the object d

Comment: I got it with: ```x$`Volume (m3)` <- eval(parse(text = as.character(myeq)))```, for input in quotes: ```"0.02^d+h"```

Comment: @IgorCobelo the above code is a reprex. That means if you start with a new R session, and use exactly this code and data, you will get exactly the same result. Have you used _exactly_ the same code or are you trying to use the code inside a longer function?